# Something Powerful

Tags: riddle

Underground

Is where I'm found

Markets rise and fall with me

As do actions of countries

Who am I?

Hint:

> You will find me on the driver's lips, attached to the car, and part of  the road in cold parts of the US.

These hints are very specific and literally true without any logical stretches. Looking for correct reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is

> Petrol

Underground

Is where I'm found

> Found in fossils which are found beneath the surface of earth.

Markets rise and fall with me

> Increase or decrease in price of petrol affects the stock market (or atleast the price of normal things). It is also used in many day-to-day things. [Here](http://www.ranken-energy.com/products%20from%20petroleum.htm) is the list.

As do actions of countries

> Every country need it for transportation. Another explanation could be that many wars have been fought for it.

You will find me on the driver's lips,

> Lipstick and lip balm both contain petroleum jelly. (Thanks to @f" for suggestion)

attached to the car,

> Used in cars. (assuming the car is not using CNG or LPG)

and part of the road in cold parts of the US.

> It's hard for diesel engine to start in cold weather. So petrol is the choice. Also, the petrol may spill out of the petrol tank on the road. And it is also used in asphalt.

Something Powerful

> Powerful enough to blow. Powerful enough to be the reason of war.

Comment: Lipstick and lip balm both contain petroleum jelly.

Comment: Part of the road is literal. So is markets rise and fall. A little more research, please...

Answer (score 13):

Is it:

> Oil

Underground

Is where I'm found

> To get to oil, you have to dig underground for this resource

Markets rise and fall with me

> Depending on OPEC (world's biggest distributor of oil) prices its oil, the markets can fall (when the price is really low like now) or rise (when the price gets high)

As do actions of countries

> Countries can react in many different ways depending on the oil industry

According to the hints...

> Oil might be seen when splashed onto the driver's face when fixing the engine, in the fuel tank of the car, and sometimes spilled on the road. The road might be the ocean as it serves as a road for ships and there are unfortunately, lots of oil spills

Comment: You came really close to the right answer. Check my edits to the hints and see if you can figure out what exactly it is.

Comment: Based on the edits, I'm guessing it's (ROT13) `crgebyrhz`, which is an ingredient in `yvc onyz`, and also used in `nfcunhyg`.  I'd post this as an answer, but it's really just piggy-backing off this one.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I have no idea what you're saying, but if you believe you're correct, by all means post an answer.

Comment: @LN6595: Sorry, since you can't do spoiler tags in a comment, I used ROT13 - basically A=N, B=O, C=P, etc.  You just add 13 to the value of the letter, wrapping around at Z.  You can find translators online, some browsers even have them built in.  I didn't want to post a new answer because it's basically just a slight variation of this one.  (Plus I already have another answer, I don't usually make 2 guesses on the same question.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Well, you got it and no one else did. I think you should post as an answer, since you are reasoning along the right lines. None of the existing answers have your tight logic.

Answer (score 10):

This is just a Guess...

> Salt

Underground Is where I'm found

> Salt is found underground.

Markets rise and fall with me

> Salt is a much needed material for markets/stores.

As do actions of countries

> Many countries have taken the initiative to try to reduce salt consumption in their specific country. Also there are many countries very dependent on salt as it used for so many things.

Comment: Salt is found on the roads during cold weather to melt away the snow

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that from the hint, but I probably should explain it more on my answer.

Comment: Try to copy the format shiron and I used

Comment: I thought the same thing, but I don't think you could ever get there without the hint...really it's the hint and not really the riddle itself that supports this answer.

Comment: I think the hint supports salt more strongly as it may be found in sweat on a driver's face as well as on the roads in cold places.

Comment: but the title is "Something Powerful"

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility:

> Iron (or Steel - works either way)

Underground

Is where I'm found

> Iron comes from mines underground

Markets rise and fall with me

> Iron is a major commodity in markets

As do actions of countries

> Iron is traded between countries.  It could also be used metaphorically to refer to warfare.

You will find me on the driver's face

> A driver is a type of golf club, typically made from iron (or wood)

attached to the car

> Many parts of a car are made from steel, which is an alloy of iron

and on the road in cold parts of the US.

> When it gets cold, some drivers put chains or iron-studded winter tires on their cars for traction.

Comment: Alternate for last one - many cold states purposefully put up guardrails on the edge of the road to protect against cars sliding off the edge. Of course, that's not exclusive to cold US states.

Comment: @Duncan: Yeah, they pretty much do that everywhere (budget permitting), regardless of climate.  I also considered that many tires are steel-belted radials, but that's also not cold-climate exclusive.  Chains and studded tires are though.  (Not just the US of course; they're used in other cold places as well, but at least the "cold" part is accurate.)

Answer (score 4):

My guess:

> Tar.

Underground:

> Can be produced from coal, wood, petroleum, or peat

Markets:

> Used at least pure form of heroine

Countries

> ["don't spoil the ship for a ha'p'orth of tar "](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/don't-spoil-the-ship-for-a-ha'p'orth-of-tar)

Attached to car

> slang for wheels

Streets

> obviously on streets and it melts on too hot streets

Answer (score 1):

You're...

> oil.

Underground

Is where I'm found

> Oil is found in mines.

Markets rise and fall with me

As do actions of countries

> Being a very widely used kind of fuel, it can force manufacturers to make smaller, more fuel-efficient products, or more people to switch to/invest in other energy sources when its price increases. Oil-rich countries can also use oil as leverage.

Comment: What was wrong with my answer?

Comment: you've provided the same answer as the top one, which was posted 11 hours ago. 'Goes without saying' is also not *that* satisfactory for a site which wants answers.

Comment: I've just edited the latter out, but there are a lot of people giving the same answer to a question and they still deserve upvotes, apparently. Or are you trying to accuse me of cheating?

Comment: Calm down. I'm not accusing you of anything. You asked why someone else voted you down. I'm saying why I think they have. That is all.

Comment: I didn't downvote but this answer is pretty much the same as my answer...